# selecting records less than current id when the value of another column is supplied

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select records less than the id of the hash values supplied? Is this even possible? I get the hashKey values from php, and based on that, need to select records that are less than the id of the rows containing that hashKey.

In pseudoCode:

```
@thisHash = '08d448b86a3b2f7d05a721ef18a8f02f';
select id from myTable where id < {id belonging to @thisHash};
```

**Table Data**

```
"id"    "country"   "hashKey"
"1"     "US"        "319f64ab2c62ee50cc9571f22e3f167b"
"2"     "US"        "9a24e339723632c1f8d4ceb82b6aa098"
"3"     "US"        "021109a71c26e252f75a69905da79d27"
"4"     "US"        "b5f7718d108c9fbc3ad546832d3632d3"
"5"     "SE"        "382155ea04502c976fccbab35dcce290"
"6"     "SE"        "79c1ff6bac2c3c36495ee9c08fc8c211"
"7"     "US"        "21e2eb330732e6d74fc19e260dd5f26f"
"8"     "US"        "e6ef5608014f4e9b697a217010c801a6"
"9"     "SE"        "a53b3d20ada68715b07d09cde2d1e7ba"
"10"    "US"        "08d448b86a3b2f7d05a721ef18a8f02f"
"11"    "US"        "a9ec1a4ce8784249a4ae1c400cc75c8f"
"12"    "SE"        "cedfb21356dd656fe2fd9b2442342b10"
"13"    "US"        "26314a78584de4efcb2b3b4069ba2c43"
"14"    "US"        "b180e756567fb9896e77ee05da9d9b14"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN`

```
SELECT t1.id
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2
    ON t2.hashKey = '08d448b86a3b2f7d05a721ef18a8f02f'
   AND t1.id < t2.id
```

**Note:** depending on the version of MySQL join-based queries have a better chance to be properly optimized.

Output:

```
| ID |
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/177e3/5)** demo

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this :

```
select id from
 myTable where id < (
   select id 
   from myTable 
   where hashkey = '@thisHash'
   );
```